# Does JSlink work in ListViewByQuery Control?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list-view, xslt-list-view-web-part, jslink

I added a ListViewByQuery control in my Application page.
I added few ViewFields using SPQuery, I customized the rendering of those fields using JSlink, The fields are showing properly in ListView, but not rendering in ListViewByQuery Control. what should I do in order to show the customized Fields in ListViewByQuery Control?